# CSS/HTML | Menu transition: Circle to square

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, css-transitions, geometry

I try to make simple css-dropdownmenu. 
My goal is to create a transition in which a dot transforms into a square if you hover over the main menu elements. With dot i mean a very small circle which cant be seen until hovered and then transforms into a square.
My menu is already able to transform the square into a circle with differant color but I cant think of a way to do it vice versa, especially because the circle first has to be 'hidden' until hovered.

Here is what i have so far:http://jsfiddle.net/eaqw4m38/3/

HTML:
    

    
        
        
        
        Test

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#s1">Menu 1</a>
                <span id="s1"></span>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Header a</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu I</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu II</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu III</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Header b</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu I</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu II</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu III</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#s2">Menu 2</a>
                <span id="s2"></span>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Header c</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu I</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu II</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu III</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Header d</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu I</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu II</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu III</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I couldnt find anything via the search that fit my question.
Thanks in advance for your answers :)
Paul

EDIT: I now know how to add such a circle and make it transparent but how do i add it to the transition? 
The problem is that i have to objects: 1. the square of the menuelement
2. the circle

How do I anymate the circle when the square is hovered and moreover i have to keep the font on top of the circle

Answer (score 1):

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2ykjdbo/

Just apply the border radius to elements at the start (when they are not hovered), and then apply the background and new color when the element is hovered while changing the border-radius to 0. As the color changes, you will see the transition from circle to square.

Code (unchanged selectors omitted):

```css
#nav > li > a {
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 49px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#nav > li:hover > a, #nav > a:hover {
    background-color: #EC7970;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: The point is i actually want the circle to appear from the bottom center of  the a tag . In the one Hand im not able to center it without setting it to relative (and then it enlarges the a Tag) and in the other Hand i have problems moving it behind the a Tag so it ist covered by the circle